# Product taken over primes

Tags: number-theory

In the book of Guy on unsolved problem in number theory, problem B 48 it is stated that

$S_n=\prod_{1}^{n} \frac{p_n +1}{p_n - 1}$ is never an integer after $n=8$. I just realized that this is related to the Sophie german conjecture on primes $q$ for which $2q+1$ is also a prime. If we know that there are infinitely many Sophie German primes then we are done.

Does this observation appear somewhere?

I reached this by realizing that if $q=2p+1$ is a Sophie Germain prime and is the $n$ th prime, then $S_n=S_{n-1} \cdot \frac{p+1}{p}$, and $p$ does not appear anywhere in the numerator of $S_n$ (we can show $2p-1$ wont be a prime), so then $S_n$ must be a fraction, and will remain so till $p$ appears in the numerator of $S_m$ for some $m\geq n$. The smallest such $p_m$ for which p appears in the numerator of $S_m$ is $4p-1$(we can only get even numbers on top, and $2p$ does not appear as if it did $2p-1$ would be a prime, but it is impossible for $p,q$ and $2p-1$ to be primes simultaneously by mod $3$ conditions), so if we can get another Sophie German prime $q' = 2p'+1$ between $q$ and $4p-1$, then $q'>q$ so $p'>p$ so $4p'-1 > 4p-1$ by repeating the same argument $p'$ appears in the denominator and we can say that the product is not an integer till the  case of $m$ when $p_m$ is not more than $4p'-1$. Now We again pick a SG prime in between $q'$ and $4p'-1$ and proceed. Thus we cover all the integers. But by the Sophie German conjecture such a prime always exists.

Comment: Are you claiming that an infinitude of Germain primes, no matter how sparse they become, is enough to show that the given product is never again an integer?

Comment: If $\frac{p_m-1}{2}$ is a prime $>3$ then $\prod_{n=1}^m \frac{p_n+1}{p_n-1}$ is not an integer. But it doesn't say anything of $\prod_{n=1}^{k} \frac{p_n+1}{p_n-1}$ with $k > m$

Comment: pls see the edit

Comment: So you meant assuming a Bertrand's postulate for the Sophie Germain's prime. And $$S_m=\prod_{n=1}^m \frac{p_n+1}{p_n-1}$$

Comment: That probably follows from the conjectured density of the SG primes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *third* edition of UPNT, Guy writes that Jud McCranie "notes the connexion with Sophie Germain primes."  There is, however, no further elaboration or reference.

Comment: I take it you have a first or second edition UPNT ;-)